# Latex fractions to mathML in Python with regex

Tags: python, regex, latex, fractions, mathml

I have some text:

```
\frac{A}{B}
```

i need to transform this text to form:

```
<mfrac>
 <mrow>
  A
 </mrow>
 <mrow>
  B
 </mrow>
</mfrac>
```

I have to use Python, and regex. `A` and `B` can be further fractions, so function must be recursive, for example text:

```
\frac{1+x}{1+\frac{1}{x}}
```

must change into

```
<mfrac>
 <mrow>
  1+x
 </mrow>
 <mrow>
  1+
  <mfrac>
   <mrow>
    1
   </mrow>
   <mrow>
    x
   </mrow>
   </mfrac>
 </mrow>
</mfrac>
```

please help with regex :)

Comment: You can't do it in full regex with the re module, because the re module doesn't have the recursion feature. However, you can install and try the alternative regex module (named: regex) that implements this feature: more information here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte What would the regular expression with recursion feature look like ?

Comment: presumably your required output is just using a meta-syntax and you don't really generate `<mrow>  1+x </mrow>` ? (the MathML should be  `<mrow><mn>1</mn><mo>+</mo><mi>x</mi></mrow>` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to match recursive pattern in default python re module,
you can do like me for recursive comments I build recently for 
css preprocessor.

Generally use re just for splitting text to tokens and then use loops
with nesting level variable to find all syntax. Here is my code:

```
COMMENTsRe = re.compile( r"""
                        //   |
                        \n   |
                        /\*  |
                        \*/  
                        """, re.X ) 

def rm_comments( cut ):
  nocomment = 0 # no inside comment
  c = 1 # c-like comments, but nested
  cpp = 2 # c++like comments

  mode = nocomment
  clevel = 0 # nesting level of c-like comments
  matchesidx = []

  # in pure RE we cannot find nestesd structuries
  # so we are just finding all boundires and parse it here
  matches = COMMENTsRe.finditer( str(cut) )
  start = 0
  for i in matches:
    m = i.group()
    if mode == cpp:
      if m == "\n":
        matchesidx.append( ( start, i.end()-1 ) ) # -1 because without \n
        mode = nocomment
    elif mode == c:
      if m == "/*":
        clevel += 1
      if m == "*/":
        clevel -= 1
      if clevel == 0:
        matchesidx.append( ( start, i.end() ) )
        mode = nocomment
    else:
      if m == "//":
        start = i.start()
        mode = cpp
      elif m == "/*":
        start = i.start()
        mode = c
        clevel += 1

  cut.rm_and_save( matchesidx )
```